# python постоянное обновление переменной, как можно реализовать?

Tags: python, cpu, psutil

```
import psutil  
CPU = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
print('The CPU usage is: ',CPU)
```

Знаю как можно реализовать постоянное обновление времени, но с CPU разобраться не могу.
Знаю, что надо импортировать еще одну библиотеку и дописать пару строк или строку в print, буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какая разница, время печатать или загрузку `CPU`? Это делается однотипно:

```py
import psutil
from time import sleep

while True:
    CPU = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    print(f'\rThe CPU usage is: {CPU}%', end='  ', flush=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, я наглупил.